# General Relativity: impact of acceleration on time, experimental setup

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, time-dilation

In [*What is relativity* by Jeffrey Bennett](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0231167261) (Amazon link), the author explains how acceleration/gravity impact time and causes time dilation. For this he takes an example of an accelerating space-ship and designs a set up that you and Al, on front and back of spaceship are sending light flashes at rate of 1 flash per second. Next he argues the following:

> " (1) The light flashes take a short time to travel from one end of the spaceship to the other, and (2) during that short time, the acceleration means that the speed of the spaceship increases. Let’s start with your point of view. Because you are in the front of the accelerating spaceship, the increasing speed will lead you to conclude that you are being carried away from the point at which each of Al’s flashes was emitted. Therefore, the light from each of Al’s flashes will take a little longer to reach you than it did when the ship was not accelerating. **As long as the spaceship keeps accelerating at the same rate, this “extra” time is always the same**, which means you’ll still see Al’s light flashing at a steady rate—but it will now be flashing slower than once per second."

I find the bold statement troubling, how does constant acceleration ensure constant 'extra' time? Since the spaceship is accelerating the distance light has to travel every time (for every new flash by Al) is increasing non-linearly, right? So the 'extra' time should keep increasing, right?

Comment: Remember that light always travels at the speed of light! You can pretend that when each flash of light is emitted, you switch to an inertial frame which has the same speed as the ship at that instant. Since velocity is relative, your current speed doesn't matter, only your acceleration does.